# Excel 2016 triggers undo upon save bug?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, excel

Excel 2016 seems to trigger a programmatically added undo level upon saving, which does not happen in earlier versions of Excel (2013, 2010, and 2007). To reproduce this apparent bug, open a new workbook and save it as a macro-enabled workbook (.xlsm file). Paste the following code into the ThisWorkbook module:

```vb
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents App As Application
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub
Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.OnUndo "foo", "modTest.Undo"
End Sub
```

Then, insert a new module named `modTest` and paste the following code:

```vb
Public Sub Undo()
    MsgBox "This is the Excel 2016 bug."
End Sub
```

Finally, save the workbook and reopen it. Enter any value in any cell to trigger the `Application.SheetChange` event. Save the workbook (you may need to do this twice, for some reason), and the message in `modTest` will appear.

Can anyone explain what may be going on here, and/or how to work around this problem? If this is indeed a bug, what is the best way to report it to Microsoft?

This code is VBA, but since this problem affects VSTO add-ins written in VB.NET and C#, too, I am including those tags.

Comment: Sometimes Microsoft Connect can be used to report bugs, but it doesn't appear that Office is on the list of available products right now.  Alternatively, a Microsoft MVP can usually give a heads up to the right product group and at least get some visibility on it (I'm an MVP - I'll give this a bit to see what others think and will forward it along to MS if the consensus is that it is indeed a bug)

Comment: You don't even need to use the event, you just need to execute `Application.OnUndo "foo", "modTest.Undo"` anywhere. At least that "works" for me. After that, I need to save two times.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct - that's a workaround in some cases, but besides the point.  You still don't have a solid, behaving event to work with (and there's cases where the application itself might fire Undo internally, and if you can't rely on the event procedure working correctly, there's no (easy) workarounds for that.

Comment: @jdl134679 I was just trying to say that I could reproduce it without the event (`App_SheetChange`) but just by executing the `.onUndo ...` anywhere, for example in the immediate window. So the issue isn't the `SheetChange` event.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct - my bad, sorry about that (thought you were suggesting that he could just call it directly as a workaround to the problem)

Comment: I would love to learn a way to properly report Office bugs. Excel 2016 has proved to have some big problems, including undocumented breaking behaviours (adding this one to the list!), and it would appear one has to burn a $500 support incident to report them.

Comment: I don't have office 2016, but, a workaround that I can think about to fix it is: 1. Catch the event after save. 2. [Call a macro to set to "0" the undo](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-and-change-a-registry-key-using-vba/) 3. [Modify the register key for undo in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211922). 4. Set Undo Register key again. In the other hand, this would be considered another bug itself (Undo won't be able for previous data before saving) ,but, it may be a less painful one than saving with an undo.

Comment: just `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean): Application.OnUndo "", "": End Sub` does the trick to avoid it via VBA...

Comment: @Dirk, thanks for the suggestion.  That does avoid the bug, but may create more problems than it solves because the user won't be able to undo after saving (OnUndo will clear Excel's undo stack).

Comment: @MacG then my excel seems broken: saving always clears my undo list. If that is different for you, then I need to run some tests...

Comment: @Dirk Let the tests begin!  I recall that used to be the case a while back, but not anymore.

Comment: Update:  Microsoft software engineers are aware of the bug and are working on a fix.  Unclear what timing may be on that, so still very much interested in viable a workaround in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have confirmed via testing and direct communication with MS software engineers and support staff that this bug is fixed in Office builds released late July / early August 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is back now on 06-06-2019
I am trapping with a variable if there are any changes that the onChange event encountered. What a pain